# Design dilemma. What's the best design?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a design dilemma wherein:

1. I have a UI action on my web page to allow the user to select a type from a list of types.
2. Each type is defined by a POJO. I need to wrap this POJO (for the type which the user has selected) in a parent class and use it to perform an action.
3. Each type can lead to a different action.

How do I design my parent class to support any type that the user selects? I want to avoid `instanceof` check while using the selected POJO later in my application.

Comment: Create an interface for all of these

Comment: Yes.That is how my current design is. But how do i avoid instanceof later?

Comment: Is the POJO a pure data object or is it part of the business logic? Or formulated differently: Can you make the POJO into a command object and be done with it?

Comment: Create a `startAction` method, or whatever you want it to be called and create a variable of the type of the interface. Later just call the `startAction `Method.

Comment: @dhke : Yes. The POJO is a pure data object. No business logic in it.

Comment: @KevinEsche That part is already done, as to my understanding. She wants to use the object later on but not as the Interface. It shall be used as the concrete type. Is that right, Priyanka?

Comment: @Fildor :  yes, exactly.

Comment: You may refer [Visitor pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)

Comment: GoF Adapter pattern (to wrap all POJOs) and Command pattern (to standardize the execute), or more simply have the POJOs implement a Command interface.

Comment: @Narendra Pathai  : Are you sure?,If i am not mistaken, visitor pattern is used when a logic is required to traverse through a collection of concrete types of a given interface type, where as in my case i need to access only one concrete type.

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil yes u r correct.. I should nt recommend it here.. It is sometimes used in place of instanceof bt is useful when there r different operations on concrete types.. So yes I take it back it should nt be used here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which solution is best depends on how you define the choices in your UI.

**The simplest way to define the possible choices is with an enum.** If you go that route, I would suggest using an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) to Map the type to the action, or (assuming the actions are mutable or need to be created per request) an action factory.

For example:

```
EnumMap<Type, Class<Action>> typeToActionMap = new EnumMap<>();
typeToActionMap.put(Type.Large, LargeAction.class);
typeToActionMap.put(Type.Medium, MediumAction.class);
typeToActionMap.put(Type.Small, SmallAction.class);
```

Above I use a the action class as a kind of factory. If the actions can be singletons, you can make the value of the map an action. As @dhke suggested, you can use Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) to to this mapping:

```
ClassToInstanceMap<Action> actionTypeToAction = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();
typeToActionMap.putInstance(LargeAction.class, new LargeAction(...));
typeToActionMap.putInstance(MediumAction.class, new MediumAction(...));
```

**If you already have a unique type for each selection** then you just need to find a way to do the mapping. A simple way is to have your types all implement a common interface:

```
public interface ActionProvider {

  Class<? extends Action> getActionClass();
```

Comment: Is it really required?. Considering i have an interface to define these types?

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil The map could instead contain the concrete class as its keys. `Map<Class<? extends Type>, Class<Action>>`

Comment: To add: It is also possible to map the source class directly without the enum, however then one must properly handle type hierarchy. Fortunately, it's been done before (e.g. guava has [ClassToInstanceMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html))

Comment: If each type had it's own class, then you can use `ClassToInstanceMap` has @dhke suggested

Answer (score 1):

Implement `ActionRegistry`.

```
class ActionRegistry {
    private static Map<ActionType, AbstractAction> REGISTRY = ...

    public static void registerAction(AbstractAction a) {
        REGISTRY.put(a.getType(), a);
    }

    public static AbstractAction getAction(ActionType type) {
        REGISTRY.get(type);
    }
}
```

Then, when you select the `type` in your UI, you can do:

```
ActionRegistry.getAction(type).run();
```

You can experiment with `AbstractAction`, so it would automatically register itself in a registry when its subclasses are instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `instanceof`, you could just override a method which then performs the UI action you need.

```
public void doAction(Type1 type) { //... }
public void doAction(Type2 type) { //... }
```

This approach can take multiple forms

```
interface Action {
    void perform();
}

public class ActionFactory {
    public static Action getAction(Type1 type) { //... }
    public static Action getAction(Type2 type) { //... }
}
```

Comment: How to you avoid the `instanceof` + cast *before* you are able to call those methods? Overload resolution is based on the declared type ...

Comment: @dhke I assumed the concrete class was known.